# Capturing CLI commands in audit logs?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, ssms

I've configured audit specification and set up audit logs infrastructure.

I'm able to see the SQL queries performed on the DBs etc via the sqlaudit files.

But I'm not sure which event group to enable to ensure os/cli commands are captured?

For example sqlcmd queries

Which amongst below can help here? https://www.logbinder.com/Products/LOGbinderSQL/EventsGenerated

Version is 2019

Comment: so you are running three instances, of which one is long out of support

Comment: @nbk removed the two, i didn't realize 2012 dead. the idea, anyway, is customer might be on various versions which isn't known, yet. So i'd want to know if this is possible, for which version etc. Do you know?

Comment: SQL Server does not distinguish between clients. Whether it's `sqlcmd`, Management Studio or a user application does not change how queries are audited; the only thing that might change is the application name (which is passed in by the client, though, and can be spoofed). SQL Server 2019 has the `BATCH_STARTED_GROUP` and `BATCH_COMPLETED_GROUP` action groups to simplify this; for earlier versions you have to explicitly capture commands separately. Extended event traces are a possibly simpler alternative if you don't need the "do or die" guarantees of the auditing feature.